# How does Lowe compute the “repeatability” of his SIFT Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

In his paper of 2004, "Distinctive Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints", he gave many figures of "repeatability" as a function of XXX, for example, figure 3,4 and 6, but he did not elaborate how to compute the "repeatability".

He actually gave an simple explanation of "repeatability" in figure 3 of page 8, which is "the percent of keypoints that are repeatably detected at the same location and scale in a transformed image".

However, **1)** how can we know weather a keypoint is detected in the transformed image, simply by checking the keypoints one by one? I do not think it is practical, since there are thousands of keypints.

**2)** How close can we consider a keypoint being repeatably detected in the SAME LOCATION? 3 pixels, 6 pixels? Or not by pixels at all?

I do not know how can I upload the paper "Distinctive Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints". Here is the link:
http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf

Comment: References/links please.

Answer (score 3):

If you notice in the first paragraph on page 9, the author goes into a bit more detail on the tolerance for saying the keypoint is detected in the same location. First, "the same scale" is given as being within a factor of `sqrt(2)` of the correct scale, which must either be known to the operator or hand labeled in the data set. Secondly, "the same location" is defined as being within σ pixels in the x and y directions, where "σ is the scale of the keypoint (deﬁned from equation (1) as the standard deviation of the smallest Gaussian used in the difference-of-Gaussian function)"

As to your more general question, the answer is unfortunately that one must indeed check the keypoints exhaustively. You gather up all the location/scale pairs where your detector fires on the transformed image, and you compare these to the true locations back in the original image. You need to have hand-recorded keypoint locations, or run a simple algorithm first (like using the basic KLT keypoint detector and just storing a list of the coordinates of the keypoints it finds and pretendting like these are "ground truth"... you'll suffer some accuracy this way but you'll be more able to automate the process).

Large scale grunt work like this (writing code to exhaustively check a ton of keypoints) is usually the stuff that gets farmed out to grad students. Blerg.

Comment: "the same location" is defined as being within σ pixels in the x and y directions, where "σ is the scale of the keypoint (deﬁned from equation (1) as the standard deviation of the smallest Gaussian used in the difference-of-Gaussian function)". So the keypoint with a large scale, say, 3 σ, will have the same tolerance with the keypoint with a small scale, say 1.5 σ?

Comment: I understand equation (1), what i do not understand is that the tolerance "σ pixels" is for all of the keypoints, which means  the keypoint with a large scale(3σ), will have the same tolerance with the keypoint with a small scale(1.5σ), which is not fair, I think. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Yes, at different scales you have different tolerances of closeness to the keypoint.

Comment: So basicly whether a keypoint is repeatably detected is defined by its location and scale. The location should be within σ pixels in the x and y directions, and the scale should be  within a factor of sqrt(2) of the correct scale. I can tell if a location is right by check whether the keypoint appears in same position of two images, if so, the keypoint pair match. However, how can I know whether the scale of the keypoint pair still match? For example, a keypoint has location (12,45) scale 1.9; in another image, a keypoint has location (67,24) scake 2.8. I check both of the images and confirm

Comment: that (12,45) of the first image is the same location of (67,24) of the second image, so I can say they are in the same location. However what about the 1.9 and 2.8? I can't say 2.8>1.9*sqrt(2), so they are not the same scale, Afterall, they are in different images. What's your opinion?